# EKEventEditViewController localization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How to change the default language in EKEventEditViewController, it is always English, even if I set AppleLanguages object manually

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem by adding a `Localizations` item to my app plist. For example, if you want your app to show the form in Spanish, add a `Localizations key` in your plist and inside it create the Spanish item.

Comment: Great, I had the same problem. Do you know what is localizations purpose?? Thanks.

Comment: To support additional localizations not included in the bundle `.lproj` directories. Check this Apple [topic](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html)

Answer (score 1):

1) In info.plist set "Localization native development region" to your languages e.g. en,de,fr and so on.

2) Add new file -> iOS resource - > Strings File and name it Localizable.
Select this file in your bundle and add on the "Utility View" your localizations.

Then your EventController should be in the correct language.